# Can Ubuntu releases that are EOL still access the default repos or not?

Tags: repository, support

> After each version of Ubuntu has reached its end-of-life time, its
>   repositories are removed from the main Ubuntu servers and consequently
>   the mirrors.[365] Older versions of Ubuntu repositories and releases
>   can be found on the old Ubuntu releases website.[366][367]

From the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Version_end_of_life

Do older Ubuntu releases completely lose access after EOL?

Comment: EOL releases loose access to the default repositories, i.e. you'll get an error if you try to install software from the repositories on such a version of Ubuntu. If you want to keep using your EOL version of Ubuntu, you need to change to the old-releases repositories as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) - the repositories for ubuntu all the way back to 4.10 are available.

Comment: This is old, but i'll add the official link - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  After a release goes EOL it's repository is moved, there is no specific period of elapsed-time on which this occurs, except it's after the EOL (17.04 for example was really quick; the following day, 17.10 however was slow in contrast with the moving occurring months later),  No tool makes this change on an installed system, it must be made by users manually (there should be no reason users need to do it, they should have accepted the offered upgrade to move to a supported release before the EOL anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Until some days i was using Lubuntu 16.04 and i had acces to the "older" repositories that they granted me with the instalation.
I think that what they do is delete the official repository, but the mirrors are maintained alive.
The problem may be if the version that you want to use is too old, you will have problems to get the lasts versions of some program(i.e firefox), and that would be a bit risky. You will no recieve security actualizations, but you can use the EOL version(I suggest an LTS version, because they have more repositories and mirrors)